# Code signing a binary file in a UWP package

Tags: uwp, code-signing

I have been working on an extension for Microsoft Edge which uses native messaging. The extension is provided by a UWP app, similar to [Microsoft's example](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Extensions-Demos/tree/master/SecureInput).

The solution for this app consists of two projects:

1. The host app (equivalent to the *NativeMessagingHostInProcess* project in Microsoft's example).
2. The desktop bridge (equivalent to the *PasswordInputProtection* project in Microsoft's example).

From this solution I create an app package.
When this package is installed, after opening Edge two processes start, one is {DesktopBridge}.exe and the other is {HostApp}.exe.
**I would like to code-sign both of these files using my code-signing certificates.**

The {DesktopBridge}.exe is simply packed inside the package, so signing it during a post build event works. However, I can't manage to sign the {HostApp}.exe.

I can use a post build event to sign it, and it will work if I'm simply building the project, but when I create an app package this event is futile. The packed executable remains unsigned.

Is there anyway I can sign it?
Or more generally speaking, is there a way to sign the executable which a UWP app runs?

Thanks :)